# R Shiny Object not found - Evaluating a strings as code

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to creat a shiny app which takes strings within a column of a data frame that are pieces of R code, and evaluate those against data frames which have been generated in the app.  Below is a working reprex of the code *outside* of the shiny app:

```
## create df with eval expressions
code_df <- data.frame(desired_outcome = c("this should be true", 
                                          "this should be false", 
                                          "this will be true or false"),
                      code_string = c('nrow(random_df) > 0', 
                                      'nrow(random_df) == 0', 
                                      'nrow(random_df) >= 100'),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)

# generate a dataframe with 1-150 rows
random_df <- data.frame(rand_binary = sample(0:1,sample(1:150, 1),rep=TRUE))

## helper function for sapply
eval_parse <- function(x){
  eval(parse(text = x))
}

## evaluate code strings
tf_vector <- sapply(code_df$code_string, eval_parse)

## add data to original df
code_df$nrow <- nrow(random_df)
code_df$tf <- tf_vector

code_df
```

If you run the code above, it will generate a 'random_df' with between 1-150 rows, then evaluate the code strings from code_df.  This code works as intended.

The problem arises when I try to implement this in shiny (code below), the implementation returns "Error: object 'random_df' not found"  when the action button is clicked.

**One other wrinkle:** If you run the non-shiny reprex code first, and do not clean the environment before you run the shiny app, the app will return the table, but it evaluates the code strings based on the non-shiny "random_df", not the newly randomly generated one from the shiny app.  You can see this based on the fact that the 'nrow' column will change in value, while the 'tf' will not change.

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)

code_df <- data.frame(desired_outcome = c("this should be true", "this should be false", "this will be true or false"),
                      code_string = c('nrow(random_df) > 0', 'nrow(random_df) == 0', 'nrow(random_df) >= 100'),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)

## helper function for sapply
eval_parse <- function(x){
  
  eval(parse(text = x))
}


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  
  new_code_df <- eventReactive(input$newDF,{
    
    # create data.frame
    random_df <- data.frame(rand_binary = sample(0:1,sample(1:150, 1),rep=TRUE))
    
    ##
    tf_vector <- sapply(code_df$code_string, eval_parse)
    
    code_df$nrow <- nrow(random_df)
    code_df$tf <- tf_vector
    code_df
    
  })
  
  output$randomdf <- renderTable({new_code_df()})

})
```

#### ui.R

```
#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Eval Code from Data Frame"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("newDF","Generate New Dataframe")
        
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('randomdf')
      )
      
    )
    
))
```

Comment: You have to give the environment (where your df lives) to the envir parameter of eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in R (and therefore shiny) are lexically scoped. This mean that functions can only see the variables defined in the environment where they themselves are defined. You are defining `eval_parse` in the global environment but `random_df` is defined in the shiny server function. This the former cannot see the latter because `random_df` is not in the gloabl enviroment like it was in your non-shiny example.

If you want to make all the server variables available to your expression, you can specify an environment to `eval()`. First change the helper so you can pass an environment

```
eval_parse <- function(x, env=parent.frame()){
  eval(parse(text = x), envir=env)
}
```

and then change your server code to pass along the function environment

```
tf_vector <- sapply(code_df$code_string, eval_parse, env=environment())
```

Comment: That worked perfect! Thanks for the explanation, I knew I was missing something fundamental about how R was executing this, but my google foo failed me on this one.